# Tree Query in sql oracle with branches and parent departments and sections

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, hierarchical-data

We have  Branches, Departments, sections ...
first table is organization has ( Branch id and name )
second table is Department has ( *Parent id , department id , department name, and Branch id )
third table is sections has ( section id , section name , department id )
I want to create tree which should show organization name , department name , section name.

- Parent id is department id start with null
  the important point here is Department can be child of another department if there is Parentid
  and sections is child of department joining department id [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F6Fe.png)

Tables script:

**1.**

```
CREATE TABLE Branch
(
  BRANCH_ID            NUMBER                   NOT NULL,
  BRANCH_NAME          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)       NOT NULL,
  START_DATE           DATE,
  END_DATE             DATE, 
  CREATED_BY           VARCHAR2(90 BYTE),
  CREATION_DATE        DATE
)
```

**2.**

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT
(
  DEPT_ID          NUMBER,
  PARENTID             NUMBER,
  DEPT_NAME            VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  STATUS               NUMBER,
  BRANCH_ID            NUMBER,
  DESCRIPTION          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  CREATED_BY           VARCHAR2(90 BYTE),
  CREATION_DATE        DATE
)
```

**3.**

```
CREATE TABLE SECTS
(
  INT_SECT_ID          NUMBER,
  DEPT_ID              NUMBER, 
  SECT_NAME            VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
  DESCRIPTION          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  STATUS               NUMBER,
  CREATED_BY           VARCHAR2(90 BYTE),
  CREATION_DATE        DATE 
)
```

**Branch table**

```
INSERT INTO Branch (BRANCH_ID,  BRANCH_NAME, CREATION_DATE)
VALUES (1,'India',sysdate);
```

**Departments table**

```
INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPT_ID, PARENTID, DEPT_NAME,BRANCH_ID)
VALUES (1,null,'HDM Department',1);

INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPT_ID, PARENTID, DEPT_NAME,BRANCH_ID)
VALUES (2,1,'IT department',1);

INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPT_ID, PARENTID, DEPT_NAME,BRANCH_ID)
VALUES (3,2,'Technial Department',1);
```

**Sections table**

```
INSERT INTO SECTS (INT_SECT_ID, DEPT_ID,SECT_NAME,CREATION_DATE)
VALUES (1,1,'Projects Managers Section',sysdate); 

INSERT INTO SECTS (INT_SECT_ID, DEPT_ID,SECT_NAME,CREATION_DATE)
VALUES (1,2,'Software Section',sysdate); 

INSERT INTO SECTS (INT_SECT_ID, DEPT_ID,SECT_NAME,CREATION_DATE)
VALUES (2,2,'Network Section',sysdate);
```

Could you please help me , I'm using sql oracle database.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you could share some sample data (create table scripts, sample data, all in "runnable" format, no screenshots) that would help a lot

Comment: Have you tried anything? Look into joins.

Comment: @Isolated yes , 
select D.PARENTID,D.DEPT_ID,D.DEPT_NAME,null,DEPT_ID link_node , 'D' ,'fa-folder-o' icon
from DEPT D, Branch B
where D.BRANCH_ID=B.BRANCH_ID 
union
select D.DEPT_ID,null,S.SECT_NAME,S.INT_SECT_ID,INT_SECT_ID link_node,'S','fa-folder-open-o' icon
from DEPT D, SECTS S
where D.DEPT_ID = S.DEPT_ID

Comment: Some sample data too pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge is that there are 3 different id columns, one for each table but the tree component only has one parent_id column. There could be confusion about what id the parent id is referring to: dept_id or a branch_id. So I prefixed the id columns with a 'B-' or 'D-' to make the ids unique. Once this is done it becomes as simple as unioning the tables and connecting them with a `CONNECT BY` clause.

```
SELECT id, parent_id, name || ' - ' ||LOWER(type) as name
FROM
(
  SELECT 'B-'||branch_id as id,
         null as parent_id, 
         'BRANCH' as type, branch_name AS name FROM branch
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D-'||dept_id as id,
         CASE WHEN parentid IS NULL THEN 'B-'||branch_id ELSE 'D-'||parentid END as parent_id,
         'DEPT' as type, dept_name AS name 
  FROM t_dept
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_CHAR(int_sect_id) as id,
         'D-'||dept_id  as parent_id, 
         'SECT' as type, sect_name AS name 
  FROM sects
)
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY (prior id = parent_id)
```

This gives me this output:

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly , Perfect. Thank you sooooo much for your time and effort

Comment: No problem - I was curious about this too and now I know how it can be done ;) Also, it's fun to work on questions that have proper sample data.

Comment: i'm wondering if i can apply this query to get hierarchy graph like uthamaselvan.wordpress.com/2018/08/21/… using google plugin. the plugin needs parent and child

Comment: Have not tried that but I don't see why not. you'll have to play with the query. There are some options on how to traverse a tree that could affect this.